# Rendering Smooth Text in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to draw text onto the screen but it always ends up being pixelated no matter what I try. A lot of people say that adding the Linear TextureFilter works or offer other solutions but they don't really work for me. This is what I have now (I'm also using a ttf font):

```
public BitmapFont generateFont(String path, double size)
{
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(path));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameters = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameters.genMipMaps = true;
    parameters.color = Color.BLACK;
    parameters.size = (int) Math.ceil(size);
    parameters.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
    parameters.minFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;
    generator.scaleForPixelHeight((int) size);

    return generator.generateFont(parameters);
}
```

I've also changed the parameter size to `(int) Math.ceil(2 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 9);` and while that makes things a little bit smoother, it's nowhere near as crisp as some other texts are.

I'm wondering what I need to do in order to get smooth text along with how I can maintain that smoothness in different text sizes across different resolutions (I'm only targeting desktop right now since I'm really just messing around with Libgdx). It just seems like there are several different ways of doing this but I just want to know what's the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: Try `minFilter MipMapLinearNearest` and `magFilter Nearest`.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Still blurry.

Comment: What size do you use?

Comment: I'm using 64 right now. However, if I change the size to `2 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 9` it makes things a little bit smoother. However, I would like to be able to specify the size of the text and have it still be smooth regardless of size.

Comment: Try multiplying by Gdx.graphics.getDensity().

Comment: I've tried that before and that doesn't help.

Comment: What does `generator.scaleForPixelHeight((int) size);` do? Do you need it?

Comment: The Javadocs says "Uses ascender and descender of font to calculate real height that makes all glyphs to fit in given pixel size." which I've seen a couple other people use, but I think it's obvious it isn't really doing anything.

Comment: How large is your viewport / camera size? Perhaps your viewport is small so the font gets really upscaled and therefor blurry.

Comment: I had it at 1000 by 1000 times the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution for `LibGDX`:

https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/fonts/distance-field-fonts

Once you get through all the possibilities of rendering huge text smoothly, you'll end up in this link.

Keep in mind that when you write a game, you have to think of all possible phone/tablet resolutions so you'll need to render a much bigger text on a tablet.

I had a great time with Distance Field Fonts. Here you can find a free generator:

https://evanw.github.io/font-texture-generator/

Comment: So what's the point of the FreeTypeFontGenerator then?

Comment: This is only true if you need really large fonts, otherwise standard MipMap should be just fine. And for your tablet comment you could multiply the size value by `Gdx.graphics.getDensity()` which will scale the font to the same size on every device :)

Comment: For smaller text objects, buttons, labels (on phones). You asked for smoothness in different text sizes - `DFF` is the answer for all your problems.

Comment: Yeah, try to scale the default GDX Arial to `100 * Density()` to display a game title :v

Comment: @Spectre That's not what I said. I said to simply multiply by the density so you get the same size for all devices. As in you already have a size 100 font and then you multiply the size by density. And DFF is definitely *not* the answer to all of your problems. DFF can be incredibly slow if you don't optimize the shader swaps.

Comment: Let's take a smallest possible resolution of a desktop application like: 1024x768. User makes a call: `(int) Math.ceil(2 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 9);`
That means `1024/9*2 = 227.55`. How to achieve this size smoothly without `DFF`? `DFF` in `GDX` is well optimized and requires only one texture with a maximum size of `1024`. You don't even have the access to the shaders.

Comment: @Spectre Solution: Don't make the font size that large! Instead decrease the viewport size that you use to render the font so you don't have to go above 64px size. And I have no idea how you can claim it to be well-optimized since there is no native support for it in `Scene2D` *because* it has poor performance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61401/discussion-between-charanor-and-spectre).

Answer (score 0):

After doing some testing it seems the problem is caused by a large font size and a large viewport size. Luckily this is easily fixed by following these simple steps:

1. Reduce `Font` size by half.
2. Reduce `Viewport` size by half.
3. Make sure the font `minFilter` is `MipMapLinearNearest` and the `magFilter` is `Linear`.
4. If this doesn't work go to step 1.

(In your case though I think the font size is just fine so I would suggest *just* reducing viewport size at first. If that doesn't work follow the steps above.)

To be clear try reducing your font size to `32` and your viewport size to `(500, 500 * aspectRatio)`, then if that doesn't work try `16` and `(250, 250 * aspectRatio)`.

This method does require you to use a separate viewport to render text with unless you want to change the viewport size of your actual game as well, so just create a new viewport of any type and make sure to apply it before rendering text:

```
gameViewport.apply();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameViewport.getCamera().combined);
batch.begin();
// Draw game stuff

textViewport.apply(true); // Center camera
batch.setProjectionMatrix(textViewport.getCamera().combined);
// Draw text
batch.end();
```

For me this produces quite satisfactory results
[image: font showcase]

Comment: Downvoter; care to explain your downvote? :)

Comment: This still doesn't seem to help. Maybe my parameters are messed up? Or maybe the font I have isn't very good (I might change it to see)? I'm assuming you are multiplying the size by the pixel density, if not, let me know what you are doing and any other parameters you might have.

Comment: @chip_s11 According to [the official wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) some fonts just won't work. Quote: **Throwing just any font at FreeType is not a super awesome idea. Some fonts in the wild are just terrible, with bad or no hinting information and will look like poopoo**. Perhaps you just happened to hit one of these fonts? Is there a link to your font?

Comment: I'm using the Lato font I downloaded from here: http://www.1001freefonts.com/lato.font

Comment: @chip_s11 Try using a standard font (Arial, Times New Roman, etc.) just to test it. If it works with those fonts you know your font is the problem.

Comment: I've tried multiple fonts now and none seem to work. I have a feeling whatever I'm doing camera wise and such is causing the issue. I'm not using a viewport right now and am just letting the camera handle everything.